# How to structure the ETL project in Azure Databricks?

Tags: azure, pyspark, etl, azure-databricks

In the past, the following project structure has been useful in etl development using pyspark (on-premises infrastructure)

[image]

Since Azure Databricks uses the concept of Notebooks, I'm not certain how this structure needs to be modified to be able to deploy etl pipelines using Azure Databricks.

Can someone please share what'd be an equivalent representation of this structure in an Azure Databricks workspace?a